# Cartojs from the ground up with congressional district as base map

Tags: dataset, cartodb

I'm trying to build a congressional district map with Cartojs. cartodb.createVis function takes in a vizjson object, so I'm looking for a vizjson link for congressional districts. I have been able to find vizjson links for US county-specific maps and European maps, but I'm looking for a vizjson link that has congressional districts, or for instructions on how I would create my own vizjson file for that since there are already shapefiles/existing datasets for congressional districts.

Another note is that when I used Carto Builder a congressional map was one of the free public datasets. I'm not able to extract this information in the form of a vizjson file though (seems like Carto Builder isn't entirely compatible with Cartojs yet) but perhaps there is a work-around this?

Please advise! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking for a `vizjson` could not be the best approach in this case because of two reasons. On the one hand, CARTO users do not usually share their `vizjson`s, and on the other, as you have pointed out CARTO.js current version is not compatible with BUILDER `vizjson`s. So I would recommend following these steps to create a CARTO.js map application:

1. Connect this "congressional district" dataset from the Data Library into your CARTO account.
2. Use [`createLayer` method](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/carto-js/api-methods#cartodbcreatelayermap-layersource--options--callback) instead of `createVis`, setting the districts dataset as a `subLayer`. [Here](http://bl.ocks.org/ramiroaznar/a0d1fbb0a757b5a45856cfed23962997) you have a working example.